# How to show comma separated value in a list using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Below is my code in vue.js where I trying to display the out put in list type like. if user give out put in the form of comma separated.

```
vue.js,angular,react.js
```

Then I want the out put in this format

```
vue.js
angular
react.js
```

This I have implemented in JavaScript but trying to achieve in vue.js please help me to complete this

*This is the updated code please tell me where I am going wrong*

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="demo">
  <span v-for="(string, index) in lists">
    <span>{{string}}</span><span v-if="index+1 < lists.length">, </span>
  </span>
</div>


<script>
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      string: ''
    };
  },
  computed: {
    lists: function(){
      return this.string.split(",");
    }
  }
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a computed property for this in combination with `split`:

```
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: function() {
    return {
      string: ''
    };
  },
  computed: {
    lists: function(){
      return this.string.split(",");
    }
  }
})
```